# Laravel Nova Search Subtitle

Tags: laravel-nova

In my Nova Resource ...

```
class Person extends Resource
```

... I have this subtitle() method (which is part of a Nova Resource Class):

```
public function subtitle()
{
    return $this->address->city;
}
```

Person Model:

```
class Person extends Model
{
    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Address');
    }
}
```

Address Model:

```
class Address extends Model
{
    public function person()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Person');
    }
}
```

$this->address->city returns NULL, why?

Of course the column "city" exits in the addresses table and there are data in the database tables, also related data.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
public function subtitle()
{
    return $this->addresses->first()->city;
}
```